# Is there a maven plugin that I can use to generate openapi spec file from JAX-RX source files

Tags: maven, jax-rs, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate openapi/swagger spec file during the build time. Maven plugin [jaxrs-gen](https://github.com/greensopinion/swagger-jaxrs-maven) works but it's very old and no longer maintained and creates very old version of swagger spec file which is no longer compatible with the new versions. Please note that openapi-generator-maven-plugin which creates java client end points from spec file works as expected, but I am trying to do the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [SmallRye OpenAPI Maven Plugin](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/tree/main/tools/maven-plugin) which works as expected and is aligned to what I needed.